# Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clausee

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

I want to use array in WHERE clause. But it doesn't work.

```
if (count(is_countable($ekkampanyaId) ? $ekkampanyaId : []) > 0) {
        $kampanyadizi = implode("','", $ekkampanyaId);
        $ekkampanyalar = $Panel_Model->urunkampanyalistele($kampanyadizi, date("Y/m/d"));
```

MY sql side

```
public function urunkampanyalistele($array , $tarih) {
    $sql = 'SELECT kampanya_ID,kampanya_indirimyuzde FROM flora_kampanya WHERE kampanya_ID IN ("' . $array . '") AND kampanya_aktiflik=1 AND kampanya_baslamatarih<' . $tarih . '<kampanya_bitistarihi';
    return $this->db->select($sql);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation like this, it makes your application vulnerable to a major security issue called SQL Injection. Use prepared statements instead: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Once you've done that, please come back and ask your question again, including all error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some quotes

```php
if (count(is_countable($ekkampanyaId) ? $ekkampanyaId : []) > 0) {
        $kampanyadizi = ",".implode("','", $ekkampanyaId)."'";
        $ekkampanyalar = $Panel_Model->urunkampanyalistele($kampanyadizi, date("Y/m/d"));
```

Comment: Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

We need to be familiar when to use single and double quotes and escape characters.

Query string should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT kampanya_ID,kampanya_indirimyuzde FROM flora_kampanya WHERE kampanya_ID IN ('" . $array . "') AND kampanya_aktiflik=1 AND kampanya_baslamatarih<'" . $tarih . "'<kampanya_bitistarihi";
```